# What was the fate of Garnet after the Weeping War?

Tags: dungeons-and-dragons, forgotten-realms

Garnet is a red dragon that lived in Cormanthor circa 600DR, and is well known for being

> Probably the only lawful good red dragon in the realms, and the key to release of the ancient Yugoloth imprisoned in Myth Drannor.

I know the sourcebook "Fall of Myth Drannor" has info on him during the Weeping War, but what happened to him after the weeping war?

If it is detailed in published works, please include references.

Comment: @sevensideddie is this better?

Comment: @Kyaaadaa Please don't answer in comments, especially not "this isn't very good/sourced/whatever" types of answers.

Answer (score 2):

## There is no answer

There simply isn't an answer in the lore, it's a mystery...

> ***Hammer 12*** **" Both Garnet and Sylvall disappeared without a trace, nor were they heard from throughout the rest of the Weeping War. While Garnet's fate has never been uncovered,** Sylvall's remains were discovered 219 years later in the Galena Mountains east of Ironfang Keep, his death apparently caused by the claws of a great wyrm." -Ruins of Adventure

https://ruins-of-adventure.obsidianportal.com/wikis/weeping-war 
http://dalelandsbeyond.forumotion.com/t20726-the-weeping-war

Comment: This is in the original sourcebok, chapter 2 "crucial campaigns" Garnet's Pyre.

Comment: I know. I believe that this is the answer.